# disable-enable the hyperlinks by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, button, hyperlink

I want to make something similar to this:
[disable-enable a hyperlink by clicking on radio-buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174201/disable-enable-a-hyperlink-by-clicking-on-radio-buttons)
but I would like to apply this method on multiple links, so I have to use the class of the elements.
Just changing the code using ".getElementsByClassName" doesn't work, and I don't understand why.
Can you explain that to me?
    
    
    
    
    StackoverFlow answer for question

```
var link;

function disable_link() { 

document.getElementsByClassName('testlink').disabled=true;

link = document.getElementsByClassName('testlink').href;

document.getElementsByClassName('testlink').removeAttribute('href');

} 


function enable_link() { 

document.getElementsByClassName('testlink').setAttribute("href",link);

} 


</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<p>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_0" onchange="disable_link();" />
Disable</label>
<br />
<label>
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio" id="RadioGroup1_1" onchange="enable_link();" />
  enable</label>
<br />
</p>
<a class="testlink" href="http://www.yahoo.com"> test </a>
<a class="testlink" href="http://www.yahoo.com"> test </a>
<a class="testlink" href="http://www.yahoo.com"> test </a>
<a class="testlink" href="http://www.yahoo.com"> test </a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Even other methods are fine.

edit: Thanks to all of you for the answers.

Comment: Using jQuery would make this easier.  Is that an option?

Comment: Sure, but how I can do it?

Comment: Why do you remove **href** when disabling is enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a HTMLCollection, so you will have to loop over it and handle each link individually.

In this case you no longer can use temporary variable to hold disabled link `href`. Simple solution would be to store removed `href` attribute in another attribute on the corresponding element.

It can look something like this:

```
function disable_link() {
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName('testlink');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].setAttribute('data-href', links[i].getAttribute('href'));
        links[i].removeAttribute('href');
    }
}

function enable_link() {
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName('testlink');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].setAttribute("href", links[i].getAttribute('data-href'));
    }
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/5z8av0xg/

Answer (score 1):

Note s in the following quote:

> The getElement**s**ByClassName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object.
>
> The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.
>
> **Tip:** You can use the length property of the NodeList object to determine the number of elements with a specified class name, then you can loop through all elements and extract the info you want.

[ http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp ]

Comment: So, you cannot assign it to the list, but items on the list, one by one.

Answer (score 0):

this line wont work because it doesn't make sense which href of testclass should be set in parameter:

```
link = document.getElementsByClassName('testlink').href;
```

Actually You dont need to remove href. instead of that you can make a not_active class and toggle this class on all links is testlink class. (workd in IE11+ and others)

```
.not-active {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

jquery to toggle class (handles both enabling and disabling):

```
function disable_link(){    
$(".testlink").toggleClass("not_active")
}
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that IE 11 is required for support of *ponter-events* on HTML elements.